# Unit Test Prime Factor C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to display the prime factors of a number. The code works, but I'm struggling with the unit test, as I'm not as familiar with it (I have to return a string in method).

```
 public class PrimeFactor
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int userInput;

        Console.Write("Please enter a number to find its prime factors: ");
        userInput = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        PrimeFactors(userInput);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string PrimeFactors(int number)
    {
        Console.Write($"Prime Factors of {number} are: ");

        // Even Numbers
        while(number % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("2 ");
            number = number / 2;
        }

        // Odd Numbers
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(number); i += 2)
        {
            while (number % i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write($"{i} ");
                number = number / i;
            }
        }

        if (number > 2)
        {
            Console.Write($"{number} ");
        }

        return number.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code above, displays the prime factors, but when doing the unit test, it keeps failing and the actual is not providing the right output.

```
 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        string expected = "2 2 2 5 ";


        // Act
        string actual = PrimeFactor.PrimeFactors(40);

        // Asset
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

When running the test, its displaying the actual as 5. I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to test what's written to the console, rather than what the method returns.  The method _returns_ `"5"` with the input _40_.

Comment: Instead of Console. Write, add each factor to a string and return the resulting one. (or better, but maybe out of scope for your challenge, make it a List)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the last prime factor (in your case `"5"`), not the string you expect. Instead of putting it into the console, return it from the function, like so:

```
public class PrimeFactor
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int userInput;

        Console.Write("Please enter a number to find its prime factors: ");
        userInput = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write($"Prime Factors of {userInput} are: ");
        string primeFactors = PrimeFactors(userInput);
        Console.Write(primeFactors);
    }

    public static string PrimeFactors(int number)
    {

        string result = "";

        // Even Numbers
        while(number % 2 == 0)
        {
            result += "2 ";
            number = number / 2;
        }

        // Odd Numbers
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(number); i += 2)
        {
            while (number % i == 0)
            {
                result += $"{i} ";
                number = number / i;
            }
        }

        if (number > 2)
        {
            result += $"{number} ";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

With this shape of the function, you can easily unit test it with the code you wrote.

If you care about memory-optimisation, you can replace string concatenation with [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0).